# Restrict Hover functionality for Mobile

Tags: android, html, css, scss-lint

We need to implement hover only for desktop but not to any other devices like (mobile and ipad).

@media (hover: hover),
@media (hover: none) and (pointer: coarse)

We have tried restricting using these media queries:

```
@media (hover: hover) and (pointer: coarse) {
        .abc:hover {
            i {
                background-color: red;
            }

    }
}
```

I expect the output of Hover should not be observed in any of devices other than in desktop (mainly during swipe/ long press), but the actual output is it is breaking in few android devices like Samsung J8(Chrome version -77.0.3865.92, Android version-9).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, this way the hover only works on screens atleast 1024px wide.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  // only put your hover in here
  .abc:hover {
    i { 
      background-color: red
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can we get any other solution to find touch device other than using resolution

Comment: There are laptops that also have touch functions now a days. Are you considering those?

Comment: Yes. For all touch devices hover should be disabled

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/or9b4dnk/ this is a very small example, but the hover works for desktop, not on screen with touch

Comment: It is not working for SamsungJ8(Chrome version -77.0.3865.92, Android version-9).